# countdown javascript with php

Tags: javascript, php, countdown

I want a countdown on my website that starts with a value from php (out of a MySQL database).

Currently I use the following function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var seconds;
  var temp;
  var tijd = <? echo json_encode($t); ?>
 
  function countdown() {
    seconds = document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML;
    seconds = parseInt(seconds, tijd);
 
    if (seconds == 1) {
      temp = document.getElementById('countdown');
      temp.innerHTML = "0";
      return;
    }
 
    seconds--;
    temp = document.getElementById('countdown');
    temp.innerHTML = seconds;
    timeoutMyOswego = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
  } 
 
  countdown();
</script>
```

But in case $t is not 10 the value is increasing with strange steps. How can I solve this? I don't have experience with javascript, so that's the problem.

Besides that, when I adding this script, the following code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

isn't working anymore, because for example " ë " is represented with a ? in the text. I don't know why this is happening?

Who can helps me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe try `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [ParseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)? "Tijd" is not the same as radix.

Comment: <meta charset="UTF-8"> Doesn't solve the problem that a ë in a php string is changed to a ?.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a human-readable counter you must use 10 in the second parameters of parseInt function

> "Specify 10 for the decimal numeral system commonly used by humans."

Then the only number you want to retrieve from database is the start of the counter.

I think you have some like this in your HTML code:

```
<div id="countdown"><?php echo $startCounterFromDB; //This is the start of the counter ?></div>
```

And in you want to keep your code, in your JavaScript you only have to change the second parameter of the parseInt function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var seconds;
  var temp;
  var tijd = 10; //always use 10

  function countdown() {
    seconds = document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML;
    seconds = parseInt(seconds, tijd);

    if (seconds == 1) {
      temp = document.getElementById('countdown');
      temp.innerHTML = "0";
      return;
    }

    seconds--;
    temp = document.getElementById('countdown');
    temp.innerHTML = seconds;
    timeoutMyOswego = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
  } 

  countdown();
</script>
```

Finally UTF-8 is a PSR standard for all files, but you don't need to use json_encode function, because you only need to print a single number.

This code will work.

Comment: Thanks, the problem with the countdown is solved. But if I add the header

Comment: Thanks, the problem with the countdown is solved. But if I add the header

`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');`

to my code. The countdown doesn't work anymore, Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

What's about some PREMADE beautifull [jquery countdown](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=jquery%20countdown)?